# How can i place tree in sidemenubar of codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Can I place a tree like structure in the sidemenubar.(i.e, I want to categorize the commands placed in sidemenubar). Something more like Accordion, expandable and collapsible.

Comment: Please explain in detail, what is your problem and what you have done so far to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you switch to `Toolbar` where you can use add component to side menu. This is also possible with the standard menu but a bit trickier see this for toolbar:

https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_toolbar

And this for side menu bar:

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/on-the-side-up-on-top.html